# Putting "a" before "strong motivation"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

As I see that the noun 'motivation' is both -countable and uncountable, I'm confused whether or not I should use an article before it.

For example, which sentence seems correct?

> Hussein has strong motivation.

Or

> Hussein has **a** strong motivation.

Comment: This question seems okay. For a learner, dictionaries' entries are confusing

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence, we put indefinite article 'a' before 'strong' as 'motivation' is a count noun here:

> Hussein has ***a*** strong motivation.

Check Oxford Dictionary's 1st entry for [motivation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motivation).

Comment: True. What do we think about this sentence then? *Some students **need motivation** to help them through school* - uncountable or countable?

Comment: Here it seems uncountable. @ Maulik V.

Comment: That's what the OP seems to be confused about. How to decide it? Say, the original example reads - *"Hussein needs motivation."* as the example in my comment. Changing 'has' to 'needs' will change its category of countable/uncountable?

Comment: "Hussein is a great employee.  He is a good leader.  He has strong motivation.  He supports other team members."  That sounds way more natural to me than adding the "a".  Contrarily, "Give the project to Hussein.  He wants to become a team lead, so he has a strong motivation to do well on this."